# Join operation error in Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

A sample of my XML database is as follows:

```
<releases>
<release id="1" status="Accepted">
    <artists>
      <artist>
        <id>1</id><name>Persuader, The</name><anv></anv><join></join><role></role><tracks></tracks></artist></artists><title>Stockholm</title><labels>
      <label catno="SK032" name="Svek"></label></labels><extraartists>
      <artist>
        <id>239</id><name>Jesper Dahlbäck</name><anv></anv><join></join><role>Music By [All Tracks By]</role><tracks></tracks></artist></extraartists><formats>
      <format name="Vinyl" qty="2" text="">
        <descriptions>
          <description>12"</description><description>33 ⅓ RPM</description></descriptions></format></formats><genres>
      <genre>Electronic</genre></genres><styles>
      <style>Deep House</style></styles><country>Sweden</country><released>1999-03-00</released><notes>The song titles are the names of Stockholm's districts.</notes><master_id>5427</master_id><data_quality>Complete and Correct</data_quality><tracklist>
      <track>
        <position>A</position><title>Östermalm</title><duration>4:45</duration></track><track>
        <position>B1</position><title>Vasastaden</title><duration>6:11</duration></track><track>
        <position>B2</position><title>Kungsholmen</title><duration>2:49</duration></track><track>
        <position>C1</position><title>Södermalm</title><duration>5:38</duration></track><track>
        <position>C2</position><title>Norrmalm</title><duration>4:52</duration></track><track>
        <position>D</position><title>Gamla Stan</title><duration>5:16</duration></track></tracklist><identifiers>
      <identifier description="A-Side" type="Matrix / Runout" value="MPO SK 032 A1 G PHRUPMASTERGENERAL T27 LONDON"></identifier><identifier description="B-Side" type="Matrix / Runout" value="MPO SK 032 B1"></identifier><identifier description="C-Side" type="Matrix / Runout" value="MPO SK 032 C1"></identifier><identifier description="D-Side" type="Matrix / Runout" value="MPO SK 032 D1"></identifier></identifiers><videos>
      <video duration="290" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHuQWcylaU4">
        <title>The Persuader (Jesper Dahlbäck) - Östermalm</title><description>The Persuader (Jesper Dahlbäck) - Östermalm</description></video><video duration="380" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rA8CTKKEP4">
        <title>The Persuader - Vasastaden</title><description>The Persuader - Vasastaden</description></video><video duration="335" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVdDhOnoR8k">
        <title>The Persuader-Stockholm-Sodermalm</title><description>The Persuader-Stockholm-Sodermalm</description></video><video duration="289" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hy47qgyJeG0">
        <title>The Persuader - Norrmalm</title><description>The Persuader - Norrmalm</description></video></videos><companies>
      <company>
        <id>271046</id><name>The Globe Studios</name><catno></catno><entity_type>23</entity_type><entity_type_name>Recorded At</entity_type_name><resource_url>http://api.discogs.com/labels/271046</resource_url></company><company>
        <id>56025</id><name>MPO</name><catno></catno><entity_type>17</entity_type><entity_type_name>Pressed By</entity_type_name><resource_url>http://api.discogs.com/labels/56025</resource_url></company></companies></release><release id="2" status="Accepted">
    <artists>
      <artist>
        <id>2</id><name>Mr. James Barth &amp; A.D.</name><anv></anv><join></join><role></role><tracks></tracks></artist></artists><title>Knockin' Boots Vol 2 Of 2</title><labels>
      <label catno="SK 026" name="Svek"></label><label catno="SK026" name="Svek"></label></labels><extraartists>
      <artist>
        <id>26</id><name>Alexi Delano</name><anv></anv><join></join><role>Producer, Recorded By</role><tracks></tracks></artist><artist>
        <id>27</id><name>Cari Lekebusch</name><anv></anv><join></join><role>Producer, Recorded By</role><tracks></tracks></artist><artist>
        <id>26</id><name>Alexi Delano</name><anv>A. Delano</anv><join></join><role>Written-By</role><tracks></tracks></artist><artist>
        <id>27</id><name>Cari Lekebusch</name><anv>C. Lekebusch</anv><join></join><role>Written-By</role><tracks></tracks></artist></extraartists><formats>
      <format name="Vinyl" qty="1" text="">
        <descriptions>
          <description>12"</description><description>33 ⅓ RPM</description></descriptions></format></formats><genres>
      <genre>Electronic</genre></genres><styles>
      <style>Broken Beat</style><style>Techno</style><style>Tech House</style></styles><country>Sweden</country><released>1998-06-00</released><notes>All joints recorded in NYC (Dec.97).</notes><master_id>713738</master_id><data_quality>Correct</data_quality><tracklist>
      <track>
        <position>A1</position><title>A Sea Apart</title><duration>5:08</duration></track><track>
        <position>A2</position><title>Dutchmaster</title><duration>4:21</duration></track><track>
        <position>B1</position><title>Inner City Lullaby</title><duration>4:22</duration></track><track>
        <position>B2</position><title>Yeah Kid!</title><duration>4:46</duration></track></tracklist><identifiers>
      <identifier description="Side A Runout Etching" type="Matrix / Runout" value="MPO SK026-A -J.T.S.-"></identifier><identifier description="Side B Runout Etching" type="Matrix / Runout" value="MPO SK026-B -J.T.S.-"></identifier></identifiers><videos>
      <video duration="365" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXqC4-ei_zE">
        <title>Mr. james Barth &amp; Alexi Delano</title><description>Mr. james Barth &amp; Alexi Delano</description></video><video duration="260" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWkM_3MQKZk">
        <title>'Dutchmaster' - Mr. James Barth &amp; A.D. (knockin' boots vol 2)</title><description>'Dutchmaster' - Mr. James Barth &amp; A.D. (knockin' boots vol 2)</description></video></videos><companies>
      <company>
        <id>266169</id><name>JTS Studios</name><catno></catno><entity_type>29</entity_type><entity_type_name>Mastered At</entity_type_name><resource_url>http://api.discogs.com/labels/266169</resource_url></company><company>
        <id>56025</id><name>MPO</name><catno></catno><entity_type>17</entity_type><entity_type_name>Pressed By</entity_type_name><resource_url>http://api.discogs.com/labels/56025</resource_url></company></companies></release></releases>
```

I am trying to get a list of titles where the title is the same as release/artists/artist/name using XQuery. I am trying to use the following code:

```
let $r := db:open("releases1","releases.xml") return
for $b in $r/releases/release
let $a := 
          for $t in $r/releases/release/artists
          where $t/artist/name/text() = $b/title/text()
          return $t
 return $b/title
```

However, I am getting wrong results. What am I doing wrong

The output is as follows:

```
<title>Stockholm</title>
<title>Knockin' Boots Vol 2 Of 2</title>
<title>Profound Sounds Vol. 1</title>
<title>Moving Cities</title>
<title>Flowerhead</title>
<title>Knockin' Boots (Vol 1 Of 2)</title>
<title>Moonchildren EP</title>.......50,000
```

I am receiving 50,000/50,000 results. This is an impossibility. "Stockholm"  is the title for the above. However,the artists' name don't match. This results shouldn't be included.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [how to post an SSCCE](http://sscce.org). What is the result you're getting, and especially what is the expected result? If an actual error occurs, what is the error message?

Comment: Please add example output to your question (by editing it), both for what you get currently and what you want to have. This is a _very important_ and relevant part of such questions to avoid confusion and lengthy chit-chat about what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: I'm not reallly getting what you want to do. You've proposed a rather small sample of your database. Putting together the _expected output_ which matches this example input should be a trivial task (as you know what you want to have) you can do in a minute or two, but is very likely to be a very clear definition and explanation what you try to achieve. I don't understand your query at all, neither. Why are you calculating `$a` if you never use it again? Is it possible you simply want to have a `return $a` in the last line?

Comment: Yes you are right. I finally understand where I went wrong. Thanks for your help and extremely sorry for the lack of clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need to embed the FLWOR expression in another one.

```
for $t in db:open("releases1","releases.xml")/releases/release/artists
      where $t/artist/name = $t/../title
      return $t
```

Comment: In that case there's no need for a FLWOR expression at all: `db:open("releases1","releases.xml")/releases/release/artists[artist/name = ../title]`. But I'm not sure this is equivalent to the original.

Comment: True. I just wanted an Xquery equivalent. Also sometimes. There are multiple artists in the complete dataset. Even if one artist name matches the title, it should show in the results

Comment: Besides, using `text()` here is potentially harmful... (it might do what you want, but in this case you want to compare elements by their string value, as Mike did). And both are XQuery, one is not an *XQuery equivalent*.